# Cast to ObjectId failed in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, casting, angular-http, objectid

When I get an element from id in Angular I get this error

```
message: "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"${id}\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Projet\""
```

Data Model

```
export interface NouveauProjet {
  _id: String;
  leadProj: String;
  nomProj: String;
  descProj: String;
  besProj: Number;
  pers: Personnes[];
  Backlog: Fonctionnalite;
}

export interface Personnes {
  name: String;
  poste: String;
}
export interface Fonctionnalite {
  fonctionnalite: String[];
  userStory: String[];
}
```

Service function

```
getProj(id): Observable<NouveauProjet[]> {
  return this.http.get<NouveauProjet[]>(
    "http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/proj/nouvProjs/${id}");
}
```

Service call function:

```
  getprojbyId(id) {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.ajoutProj.getProj(id).subscribe(
      response=> { this.Projet=response;
      console.log(this.Projet)},
      error =>console.log(error)
    );
```

When I use Postman http request send me back the right data. but not through angular httpClient module

Postman response :

```
  {
    "_id": "5a3fa574e09f323bf71dd9f2",
    "descProj": "jkj",
    "leadProj": "kjkj",
    "nomProj": "kjk",
    "__v": 0,
    "backlog": [],
    "pers": [
        {
            "name": "kjkj",
            "poste": "kjjk",
            "_id": "5a3fa574e09f323bf71dd9f3"
        }
    ]
  }
```

Here's also my back-end route :

```
  .route("/nouvProjs/:nouvProj_id")
  .get(function(req, res) {
    NouvProj.findById(req.params.nouvProj_id, function(err, nouvProj) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      } else {
        res.json(nouvProj);
        console.log(nouvProj);
      }
    });
  })
```

Comment: Mind posting the model of what you’re trying to map to, as well as the response data from postman?

Comment: `console.log(req.params.nouvProj_id)` in your backend route, to see if frontend passing correct id

Comment: I get this `${id}`

Comment: I found the solution, I deleted `this` in  ` this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'); 
`